# Autodesk Maya on Ubuntu 19.10 / 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 19.10

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/installing-maya-2020-ubuntu.html

this user guide is broken I don't know how many ubuntu versions ago it broke, my guess is at 18.10. It seemed to work at ubuntu 18.04 it cannot possibly have worked beyond.

first off, they try to use as many deprecated 32 libs as humanly possible and second they make you convert an rpm to a deb.

start your own licensing server... then, finally install. and then a whole bunch more steps

it is... the most intentionally nuts install guide I have ever seen but it's main issue is that it's out of date.

example:

```
$ sudo gdebi libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: multiarch-support
```

How do you install maya today?

Comment: I'm not going to try it but where are you asked to install 32-bits libs?

Comment: What release are you asking about?  Your title mentions 19.10 & 20.04?  Certain 32-bit libs are still supported even if the number has reduced.

Comment: libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64 depends 32bit libs. I am on ubuntu 19.10, but when ubuntu 20.04 comes out autodesk won't have updated their guide.

Comment: I just installed `libxp6` and no other dependency was mentioned, let alone 32bit libs.

Comment: `E: Package 'libxp6' has no installation candidate` you're not on ubuntu 19.10 then.